# MySql password for service Mysql@server-ip:3306

Tags: mysql

I created a new user and when I try to connect to the db remotely via the new user I get this message and none of the passwords I use are correct. I can login to root no problem. I checked and port 3306 is open and everything since root works fine. I'm losing my mind over this.

[message box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zDPN.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the host when creating a user on MySQL:

```
CREATE USER 'johndoe'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'somesupersecurepassword';
```

Replace `localhost` for your public IPv4.

For testing, you can replace `localhost` for `%`, which should allow all hosts.

```
CREATE USER 'johndoe'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'somesupersecurepassword';
```

Comment: I already have the users set up properly, granted all privileges and nothing. Tho it is weird that if I grant the root user all the permissions it starts denying the access to that.

Comment: @noob_dev Can you include all commands you ran to create your user and grant access to that user? (With the password and the server IP hidden, of course) If you could include the exact error message, that would also help.

Comment: well i create a user using CREATE USER 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass'; and then i grant him all privileges using GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass' WITH GRANT OPTION; pretty simple stuff, the picture i posted is the only essage box that pops up, if i enter the client users passwird it says access denied.